# $S$ is continuous with Weak * topology from $Y^*$ to $X^*$ if an only if $S=T^*$ for some $B(X,Y)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

How to prove that prove that $S$ is weak$^*$-continuous from $Y^*$ to $X^*$ if  an only if $S=T^*$ for some $T\in B(X,Y)$

Thanks for any hints.

To show that  $T$ is continuous is straight forward but inverse is hard.

Comment: This is ridiculous. A perfectly normal question in functional analysis is closed by 5 users, where four of them have zero reputation in the tag, and the other 330.

Comment: *Anyway, while we wait for reasonable people to look at this question, here is an answer so I don't lose what I spent 15 minutes typing*. If $S=T^*$, and $f_j\to f$ weak$^*$ in $Y^*$, then for any $x\in X$
$$
Sf_j(x)=f_j(Tx)\to f(Tx)=T^*f(x)=Sf(x). 
$$
So $S$ is weak$^*$-continuous. 

*(continued)*

Comment: Conversely, assume that $S$ is weak$^*$-continuous. We know that what our $T$ should satisfy it is exists: $Sf(x)=f(Tx)$. So let us use this to define $T$. 
For any $x\in X$, consider the functional on $Y^*$ given by $\alpha_x:f\longmapsto Sf(x)$. By hypothesis this is weak$^*$-continuous; the weak$^*$-continuous functionals are bounded, so $\alpha_x\in Y^{**}$. *(continued)*

Comment: But, also, [a weak$^*$-continuous functional on the dual is in the predual](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183869/weak-continuous-linear-functional-is-in-the-predual). So there exists $y\in Y$ with $\alpha_x(f)=f(y)$ for all $f\in Y^*$. Define $Tx=y$. Note that $y$ is unique because $Y^*$ separates points in $Y$. From there we deduce that $T$ is linear. Finally,
$$
\|Tx\|=\sup\{|f(Tx)|:\ f\in Y^*,\ \|f\|=1\}=\sup\{|Sf(x)|:\ f\in Y^*,\ \|f\|=1\}\leq\|S\|\,\|x\|.
$$So $T$ is bounded with $\|T\|\leq\|S\|$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Agreed. I like this question just fine as is, and expect any attempts to add "context" would just clutter things up and make it less useful for future readers.

Comment: Thanks Nick. If not enough people appear to reopen it, I'll post it and answer it myself. Meanwhile, another user is scared away from the site, thanks to the *closing brigade*.

Comment: So I already posted the question and answer (I'll delete it if this one gets reopened), so that I keep what I typed.