# $B(X^{**})$ is the $w^*$-closure of $B(X)$ in $X^{**}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

I am reading Bollobás' Linear Analysis. Chapter 8. Theorem 6., as the title says:

> $B(X^{**})$ is the $w^*$-closure of $B(X)$ in $X^{**}$

The proof starts by saying that i) $B(X^{**}$) is $w^*$-closed, and ii) $B \subset B(X^{**})$ where $B$ is the $w^*$-closure of $B(X)$ in $X^{**}$. Then, suppose that there is $x_0^{**} \in B(X^{**}) \setminus B$. By the separation theorem, there is a bounded linear functional $x_0^{***}$ on $X^{**}$ such that
$$\langle x_0^{***}, b \rangle \leq 1 < \langle x_0^{***}, x_0^{**} \rangle$$
for every $b \in B$. By considering $x_0^{*}$, the restriction of $x_0^{***}$ onto the subspace $X$ of $X^{**}$, we see that $\langle x_0^{*}, x \rangle \leq 1$ for every $x \in B(X)$, thus $\| x_0^{*} \| \leq 1$. This far everything is clear. To finish up the proof, the book argues as follows:
$$1 \geq \langle x_0^{*}, x_0^{**} \rangle = \langle x_0^{***}, x_0^{**} \rangle > 1$$
claiming contradiction.

I don't really understand why $\langle x_0^{*}, x_0^{**} \rangle = \langle x_0^{***}, x_0^{**} \rangle$. I see that we can view $x_0^*$ as an element of $X^{***}$, but what guarantees, that this is the same element as $x_0^{***}$?

Comment: Is it possible that the book argued that (i) $B(X^{**})$ is $w^{*}$-closed in $X^{**}$ and (ii) that the $w^{*}$-closure of the embedded image of $B(X)$ into $X^{**}$ is contained in $B(X^{**})$? If so, the result follows from a separation argument on $(X^{**}, w^{*})$. If not, then it is not obvious as to how the result follows.

Comment: You’re right about i) and ii), but I still don’t see why that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that as $B$ is a closed convex subset of $(X^{**}, w^{*})$ and as $x_{0}^{**}\not\in B$, it follows from a separation argument that there exists some $x_{0}^{***}$ in the dual of $(X^{**}, w^{*})$ which strictly separates $B$ and $x_{0}^{**}$. But as continuous linear functionals on $(X^{**}, w^{*})$ are elements of the form $x^{***}\in X^{***}$ where there is some $x^{*}\in X^{*}$ such that $\langle x^{***}, x^{**} \rangle = \langle x^{**}, x^{*} \rangle$ for all $x^{**} \in X^{**}$, it follows that there is some $x_{0}^{*}\in X^{*}$ such that $\langle x_{0}^{***}, x^{**} \rangle = \langle x^{**}, x_{0}^{*} \rangle$ for all $x^{**} \in X^{**}$. Consequently, $x_{0}^{*}$ is the desired element.

It is also worth mentioning that this theorem is known as Goldstine's theorem.

Comment: Ah okay. So the part I was missing is that $x_0^{***}$ being a linear functional on $(X^{**}, w^*)$, it is the canonical embedding of an element $x^* \in X^{*}$ into $X^{***}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct if you have that $x_{0}^{***}$ is continuous as in the question.

Comment: And I guess this statement follows from the fact that $w^*$ is defined to be the weakest topology making the induced linear functionals continuous, so if $x_0^{***}$ wasn't like that, it couldn't be continuous. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem. For the characterisation of the dual, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183869/weak-continuous-linear-functional-is-in-the-predual) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709781/intersection-of-kernels-and-linear-dependence-of-functionals?noredirect=1&lq=1).